# Early 2000s(?) science-fiction short-story-a-week-style website with a large archive

Tags: story-identification, online-resources

I stumbled across a story-a-week-style science-fiction site many years ago, read hundreds of pieces from the archives, then somehow lost track of it. I'd love to find it again but have no idea where to start looking.

- I *think* it had a number in the name—something like "1000 Futures", but that specifically isn't it.
- It probably dates back to the early 2000s, if not earlier—I came across it around 2005-2010.
- It had an extensive archive—long enough that I got less than a third of the way through it over the course of several months.
- The stories were by a variety of authors, but I recognized at least 3-4 distinctive styles and series of stories set in the same world, so there were clearly some staff writers or regular contributors.

Pieces I remember included:

- A story (maybe several) using the [spindizzy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spindizzy) concept from James Blish's *Cities in Flight* et al. One of these stories also included a special explosive whose blast is always perpendicular to the local gravity field, cutting down trees and such without marking the ground.
- A story where a man falls through a tunnel that leads to a parallel world, in which motors and generators were never invented but the inhabitants have mastered electro*statics* to an incredible degree—instead of propellers they use charged grids to propel ionized air, they can precisely manipulate the shape of clouds of charged gas (which they use to distribute a knockout gas), etc.
- Another man-ends-up-in-parallel-world story: Automation is nonexistent and the residents are struggling to keep up with the maintenance/operation of equipment to beat back an ever-encroaching jungle. The visitor introduces simple concepts like the flyball governor and revolutionizes their industry.
- A series of descriptions of fantastical cities—sense-of-wonder pieces with no real plot. My memory of this is very vague, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  This sounds like a fan-fiction site, as opposed to a library of stories by recognized authors.  Is that the case?

Comment: @DavidW maybe not _fan_-fiction, rather regular fiction (not in an already-existing universe). Daniel, do you happen to remember anything about what the site looked like?

Comment: DavidW, no, not fan fiction, but I don't think they were by "recognized authors" necessarily—a lot of them might have been open submissions, though there were definitely some recurring authors.

Comment: Jenayah, it's been so long I'm pretty vague, but I remember a blue-ish theme, and the archives page was one looooooooong list, not paginated. If they haven't changed the design it would look pretty dated these days.

Comment: drewbenn, definitely not all by the same author—there were some regular authors, but probably many dozens contributed at least one story.

Comment: https://dailysciencefiction.com/?

Comment: Blish's Okie stories did include that gravity-aligned explosive. Its name was an acronym, maybe TDX.

Comment: Something like [this perhaps](https://web.archive.org/web/20060103070049/http://www.scifi.com/scifiction/archive.html) ?